# PHP Query Issue

Tags: mysql

I have this query which I would like to insert data into two tables.

It inserts into the first but not the second, any ideas why?

```
$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (UserID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, TelephoneNumber, Image, Status) VALUES ('NULL', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$EmailAddress', '$TelephoneNumber', '$ran2$ext', '0')") ;

$newid = mysql_insert_id($result1);

$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO voting (id, EntryID, item, vote, nvotes) VALUES ('NULL', $newid, 'vt_img353', '0', '0')") ;
```

Comment: Have you checked the return values of mysql_query? Have you tried calling 'mysql_error' on the failed query? We will need a bit more information. Also, you should take care that you're escaping your strings properly.

Comment: You should put NULL, not 'NULL' ...

Comment: Just a reminder - don't forget to sanitize your data to protect against SQL injection.   It doesn't look like you're doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I have tried the error message and I get "Duplicate entry '' for key 1", I have removed the id as it is Null now, so key one is the EntryID. ANy ideas?

Comment: Also, I get this "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'vt_img353', '0', '0')' at line 1"

Comment: @craigclicky - you'll need to provide the actual query for someone to help you with that. Put the query in a variable (`$sql`) and echo it out before executing it in MySQL. Also, we'd need to see the definition for this table - I suspect you're inserting strings into integer columns.

Comment: @craigclicky - please review the answers from Fluffeh and juergen_d, and respond/tick as appropriate; thanks. Ping me here, and I'll undownvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to insert a null, don't use quotes around it:

```
INSERT INTO voting 
    (id, EntryID, item, vote, nvotes) 
    VALUES (NULL, $newid, 'vt_img353', '0', '0')
```

As juergen d correctly points out, if you don't want to insert a column you can just skip it, but this will only work if you name the columns you are inserting first. It won't work in:

```
INSERT INTO voting 
    VALUES (NULL, $newid, 'vt_img353', '0', '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO voting (EntryID, item, vote, nvotes) VALUES ($newid, 'vt_img353', '0', '0')") ;
```

If you don't want to set a column you can leave it. Your `id` column is probably an auto-increment column. If you leave it from your insert statement it will be filled automatically.

And if you want to set it explicitly  to `NULL`then leave the quotes. Otherwise you would set the column to the **string** `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer *per se*, but very useful all the same. To make your code more readable - both in your IDE and on forums such as this - bear in mind you can indent it. Try this:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO entries (
        UserID, FirstName, LastName,
        EmailAddress, TelephoneNumber, Image,
        Status
    )
    VALUES (
        NULL, '$FirstName', '$LastName',
        '$EmailAddress', '$TelephoneNumber', '$ran2$ext',
        '0'
    )
");
```

This helps keep to a reasonable line length (I use 120 chars) and helps reduce bugs that lurk off the right-hand side of your screen.